# When to emphasize text in formal texts?

Tags: best-practices, emphasis

Text can be emphasized in LaTeX using `\emph` or `\textit`. For what kinds of text or situations is it recommended to use such emphasis in formal texts? For example, in an article, paper or thesis, when and on what elements should one apply emphasis (or italics)?

Comment: You forgot about `\textsl`...

Comment: @Ashwin, this might belong on [English Language & Usage](http://english.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 18):

On the *method* for creatîng emphasis: It's better to use `\emph` than `\textit`, for two reasons. First, `\emph` -- in keeping with LaTeX's philosophy of separating logical markup from content -- stresses the logic behind the emphasis-creating command, whereas `\textit` mixes it up with a reference to the actual font shape (italics) used to create the emphasis. Should you ever decide to use, say, a slanted roman font rather than a true italic font for emphasis, doing so is trivially easy if you've been using the `\emph` command all along, but it'll involve tracking down, checking, and editing lots of `\textit` commands if you've been using the latter command. In addition, if your main text font is a sans-serif font, the associated emphasis-oriented font is frequently a slanted sans-serif font rather than a true italic; in such circumstances, using the command `\textit` is bound to create confusion.

Second, and maybe of lesser importance, `\emph` lets you create emphasis-within-emphasis, meaning that if you need to emphasize a particular word or two within a sentence that's already emphasized, then the interior `\emph` command will automatically switch to "regular" upright (usually Roman) font. Much easier to achieve than if you've been using `\textit` commands and then have to figure out the command (`\upshape`) to invoke the upright font by hand.

Separately, you ask *when and where* to use emphasis in "formal" texts; by "formal texts," I assume you mean texts that don't consist of listings of computer code, say. A very good general reference on the topic of the use of emphasis is Robert Bringhurst's book, "The Elements of Typographic Style." Another resource is the Wikipedia page [Emphasis (typography)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emphasis_%28typography%29).

In formal typography, preference is definitely given to using an italic font (or possibly a slanted-roman font) for providing emphasis within running text instead of using a **boldface** font or, gasp, underlining words. Which words and parts of text need to be emphasized depends crucially on what the document is all about. Theorems, corollaries, etc. are often typeset in italics, presumably both to highlight the importance of the material *and* to provide a visual offset from the material that comes before and after it. In fiction literature, thoughts that a character expresses to him/herself without saying them out loud are frequently typeset in italics; here the usage clearly aims at providing a visual signpost. Foreign-language words in running text are also frequently typeset in italics. (At least that's the case in English; I have no idea how it's done in other languages whose written form derives from the Latin alphabet.) In the case of typesetting foreign language words, the use of italics serves mainly to flag the special form/usage of the words to the readers; emphasis is a minor aspect.

Comment: +1 for using only italics (or slanted fonts) in formal texts.

Comment: It is worth to add that in any language, emphasis is mandatory for the specie names by the Zoologial Nomenclature rules: "The scientific names of genus- or species-group taxa should be printed in a type-face (font) different from that used in the text; such names are usually printed in italics". As the "emphasis" is the point, in theory is better  `\emph` than `\texttit`. In practice is indifferent. It is simply a bad idea use another kind of emphasis. But what if the text is already in italics? Well,  ... don't let that happen.

Answer (score 6):

From Knuth's TeX Book, here is some consideration:

> Typographic conventions are presently in a state of transition,
>   because new technology has made it possible to do things that used to
>   be prohibitively expensive; people are wrestling with the question of
>   how much to use their new-found typographic freedom. Slanted roman
>   type was introduced in the 1930s, but it first became widely used as
>   an alternative to the conventional italic during the late 1970s. It
>   can be beneficial in mathematical texts, since slanted letters are
>   distinguishable from the italic letters in math formulas. The double
>   use of italic type for two different purposes -- for example, when
>   statements of theorems are italicized as well as the names of
>   variables in those theorems -- has led to some confusion, which can
>   now be avoided with slanted type. People are not generally agreed
>   about the relative merits of slanted versus italic, but slanted type
>   is rapidly becoming a favorite for the titles of books and journals in
>   bibliographies.